# gsub, bracketed content occasionally bound by newline instead of closing bracket

Tags: r, regex, web-scraping, gsub

I'm trying to clean up some text strings, so that I can cleanly parse out some script information.  For these tables, bracketed information represents either location or blocking notes for a script.

I'd like to take all bracketed information, and delete the brackets and all their containing characters.  The wrench in the works is that since the data were all originally written manually, not all bracketed information or notes actually have a closing bracket.  So - I would like to identify:

- [
- any character except for a closing bracket, 0 or more times
- EITHER a closing bracket, or a newline indicator \n

Sample data, one very long string (abbreviation my own).  Typically each string will be an entire episode's script:

```
"[Bridge]\r\r\n\r\r\n SPOCK: Check the circuit. \r\r\n [Pike's Quarters \r\r\n BOYCE: Boyce here.\r\r\n"
```

I have tried several permutations of gsub, primarily along these lines:

```
    df$script <- gsub("\\[[^\\]]*[\\]|\\n]", " ", testdf$script)
```

Which I believe should grab:

```
    \\[         an open bracket
    [^\\]]*     any character except for a closed bracket, 0 or more times
    [\\]|\\n]   either a closed bracket, or a new line metachar
```

but I am coming up empty each time.  I've tried other variations on that gsub line, since my regex-fu is what's holding me back.  These have all been attempted with no change to my string:

```
    df$script <- gsub("\\[[^\\]]*[\\]\\n]", " ", testdf$script)
    df$script <- gsub("\\[[^\\]]*[\\]|\\n]", " ", testdf$script)
    df$script <- gsub("\\[[^\\]]*[\\](\\n)]", " ", testdf$script)
    df$script <- gsub("\\[[^\\]]*[\\]|(\\n)]", " ", testdf$script)
```

I am aware that regex'ing scraped HTML will probably get me a stink face here; unfortunately, it's the only tool I have to tackle this string.  I've had varying degrees of success with some other language regex simulators, but there is something about R gsub that is not on board how I'm trying to handle metacharacters.  Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: What about `gsub("\\[|[^]]*[]]|\\n|\\r", "", s)`? (`s` is the string.)

Comment: *"regex'ing scraped HTML will probably get me a stink face here"* Not at all, but if you also post the scraping code, we might be able to tweak that to give less dirty broken output?

Comment: @RuiBarradas - can you walk me through your intent with that matching string?  I added some escape characters and things happened -- but what I was expecting.  It removed the opening bracket, along with all /r and /n metacharacters.  It's quite possible I butchered your original intention though.  I tried gsub("\\[|[^\\]]*[\\]]|\\n|\\r", "", s)

Comment: @smci of course! I'll first apologize, this is my "learn how to scrape HTML" side project, so nothing is probably tidy or possibly even easy to read.  Link here - https://github.com/omgitsjessie/trekvis/blob/master/trek_getdata.R

Comment: @smci Actual code that is probably most relevant: 
#function to pull the script from a given URL:
beam_me_in <- function(url) {
  url_string <- url
  html_readin <- read_html(url_string) #Return an XML doc of the episode's site
  xml_find_all(x=html_readin, xpath = "//tr")  
  td_element <- html_nodes(html_readin, css = "td") #extract contents w/ css selector
  script_text <- html_text(td_element)  #extract text from the body
  return(script_text)  #return the script for that URL's episode.  Unformatted.
}
from 712 URLs along these lines: http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/1.htm

Comment: Try [`gsub("\\[[^]\r\n]*(?:]|\\R)", " ", x, perl=TRUE)`](https://ideone.com/vNORfa). A [regex demo is available here](https://regex101.com/r/0QTUPX/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew YES!  Perfect!!  I did not even think of flying my perl flag there.

Comment: @smci I'd more than welcome any comments or critique on that HTML scraping code; but for now I am good to limp along with the current implementation.  Thank you all!

Comment: I will post the answer then

Comment: @omgitsjessie sure. The very popular Python package BeautifulSoup excels at parsing broken or mismatched HTML. If you're not wedded to R you might give it a try, or at least use it to write an intermediate representation which you can then process further in R.

Comment: ...or try [R package rvest](https://discuss.analyticsvidhya.com/t/what-are-some-libraries-in-r-similar-to-the-beautifulsoup-package-in-python/2125/3), written by the hyperproductive Hadley

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following PCRE regex (with `perl=TRUE` argument passed to `gsub`)

```
\[[^]\r\n]*(?:]|\R)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0QTUPX/1/).

**Pattern details**

- `\[` - a `[` char
- `[^]\r\n]*` - 0+ chars other than `]`, CR and LF
- `(?:]|\R)` - either a `]` (`]`) or (`|`) line break sequence (`\R`)

[R demo](https://ideone.com/vNORfa):

```
x <- "[Bridge]\r\r\n\r\r\n SPOCK: Check the circuit. \r\r\n [Pike's Quarters \r\r\n BOYCE: Boyce here.\r\r\n"
x <- gsub("\\[[^]\r\n]*(?:]|\\R)", " ", x, perl=TRUE)
x
## => [1] " \r\r\n\r\r\n SPOCK: Check the circuit. \r\r\n  \r\n BOYCE: Boyce here.\r\r\n"
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you've saved the day :)